# How to update array of records if not exist insert, without id?

Tags: mysql

i tried to do like this:

```js
 INSERT INTO hlr_client_country
          (perform_hlr, client_id, mcc, dial_code)
        VALUES
         (1,2,202,30),(1,2,204,31)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        id         = 'id',
        client_id  = 'client_id',
        mcc        = 'mcc'
```

but query always inserts new and new records.

I want to update first and if record not exists insert one
Help please

Comment: Do you have a `PK` configured on the table?

Comment: @sagi, yes, id is PK, autoincriment, unique

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE title_1 ='$title_1' ");

if( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET column = '$value' WHERE title_1 = '$title_1' ");
}
else
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (title_1) VALUES ('$title_1') ");
}
```

^_^